# Add all Java tree nodes and its own value to HashMap using java

Tags: java, tree

I have a JavaTree ,its all node has a name and assigned value. I want to add these names and values to HashMap. But, I can't take all results to HashMap finally. It take only one value in one time. I used following code.

```
public HashMap<String, Double> printAll(TreeNode root) {

  HashMap<String, Double> allContainNodes = new HashMap<String, Double>();
  NodeInfor nodeObj = (NodeInfor) ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) root).getUserObject();

  Enumeration children = root.children();

  if (children != null) 
    while (children.hasMoreElements()) {
      printAll((TreeNode) children.nextElement());
    }
  }

  allContainNodes .put(nodeObj.name, nodeObj.specVal);
  return allContainNodes;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the error message ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It didn't give any error message. But, I can't take all results to HashMap finally. It take only one value in one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lose the printAll values in your recursive call, try something like

```
allContainNodes.putAll(printAll((TreeNode) children.nextElement()));
```

Comment: You mean instead of `allContainNodes .put(nodeObj.name, nodeObj.specVal);`  ? It gave an error  `Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Collections$EmptyEnumeration.nextElement(Unknown Source)`

Comment: No, i meant instead of `printAll((TreeNode) children.nextElement());` in your loop

Answer (score 2):

You could for example pass the instance of the HashMap to the next level of the iteration, modifying your method like following (only the first run should instanciate it),

```
public HashMap<String, Double> printAll(TreeNode root, HashMap<String, Double> allContainNodes) {

  if (allContainNodes==null){
   allContainNodes = new HashMap<String, Double>();
  }
  NodeInfor nodeObj = (NodeInfor) ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) root).getUserObject();

  Enumeration children = root.children();

  if (children != null) 
    while (children.hasMoreElements()) {
      printAll((TreeNode) children.nextElement(), allContainNodes );
    }
  }

  allContainNodes.put(nodeObj.name, nodeObj.specVal);
  return allContainNodes;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.